# Extending Number to get a natural number

Tags: javascript, numbers, prototype

I'm quite intrigued after reading in Crockford's JavaScript: The good parts, that doing this:

```
Function.prototype.method=function(name, func){
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this
}
```

I can extend Number, so this would work:

```
Number.method('integer',function(){
  return Math.round(this)
});
```

44.4.integer();//44

but when trying to get a Positive Integer (natural number ) is throwing an error:

```
Function.prototype.method=function(name, func){
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this
}
Number.method('natural',function(){
  return Math.round(Math.abs(this))
});

   -44.4.natural();// error or doesn't work
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
console.log((-44.4).natural());
```

Your problem is that 44.4.natural() gets executed first, then you print the negative of that.

```js
    Function.prototype.method=function(name, func){
      this.prototype[name] = func;
      return this
    }
    Number.method('natural',function(){
      return Math.round(Math.abs(this))
    });
    
    console.log((-44.4).natural());
```

Answer (score 1):

When you say "error" I assume you mean "incorrect result".

The problem is that `-44.4.natural()` is effectively `-(44.4.natural())`. If you look at `this` within the `natural` method, you'd see that it's `44.4`, not `-44.4`.

JavaScript doesn't have a negative number literal format. It uses the negation operator instead. Precedence rules mean that the method call is done first, then the negation.

If you want to use `-44.4` as your value, put it in a variable:

```
let a = -44.4;
console.log(a.natural()); // 44.4
```

Live Example:

```js
Function.prototype.method=function(name, func){
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this
}

Number.method('natural',function(){
  return Math.abs(this)
});

let a = -44.4;
console.log(a.natural());
```

or use `()`:

```
console.log((-44.4).natural()); // 44.4
```

Live Example:

```js
Function.prototype.method=function(name, func){
  this.prototype[name] = func;
  return this
}

Number.method('natural',function(){
  return Math.abs(this)
});

console.log((-44.4).natural()); // 44.4
```